# Can't render layout in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application which was written for rails 2. I'm upgrading to rails 3. Most of the functionality of my app works but it does not render any layout.
I'm using default 'erb' engine.

I've explicitly called a layout in my controller but it just does not render even the simplest layout

```
layout 'application'
```

It does not throw any error.

When I create a new project and try to render a layout in it, it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you give more details?
File name of the application layout?
Related gems you're using HAML or others?
Anything you may think could be related to the issue?

Comment: File name of the application layout is 'application.html.erb' and I have a lot legacy code in my app. Can it cause such nuisance?

Comment: Is your layout located in `Rails.root/views/layouts/*` ?

Comment: Yes, It is in the /views/layouts/* directory.

Comment: Can you explicitely call layout "layouts/application"   ?

Comment: I tried to call them explicitly but still they aren't working. It does not throw an error but at the same time it does not get rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
render :layout => 'application'
```

You can check it out here :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can still use layout "my_layout" from the controller. Check 2.2.13.4 Layout Inheritance in the guide :)

Comment: But render :layout => 'application' works only within the method. Is there a way to specify layout for entire controller?

Comment: I added before_filter and then called a method which will render the layout. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Dominic Goulet: Why we should explicitly render application layout as it would be the default one when the application is loaded?

Comment: It was more about the syntax than the actual layout called. The OP had a bad syntax for it. Read the OP before downvoting answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The reason that the default layout for the controller isn't being used is because the controller is not properly initialized. This happens when there is an included module in your controller hierarchy that has an 'initialize' method that doesn't call super. This stops the initialize chain and you end up with this sort of problem.

You can read more about it here:

http://www.spiffystores.com/blog/2013/01/04/problems-rendering-a-layout-in-rails3/

Comment: Oh boy, you just saved my life. My problem was exactly with a 'initialize' method which was not calling super. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Having a similar issue, my controller has 97 ancestors -.-

Comment: just wondering, I also have 80 so ancestors, is there any handy method to  figure out which of these is responsible..?

Comment: For anyone running into the same kind of issues, one my end, it seemed to be one of the modules installed by ActiveAdmin or ActiveAdmin-Globalize that was causing the issue.