# View is being rendered without layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, erb

I just created a new project with Rails 3.2.11 on Windows and my views are being rendered without a layout by default.

I have a controller as following:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    @ini=Date.new(2013,01,01)
    @end=Date.new(2013,12,31)

  def show
  end
end
```

My view `show.html.erb` is being rendered without a layout, even if I force `layout :application` on the controller it doesn't work.

The only way I managed to fix this behavior is explicit telling show method to render with layout.

```
def show
  render :layout => 'application'
end
```

Am I missing something?

Shouldn't the default application layout be selected for all actions by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer for my problem reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151277/305116).

The problem was with my controller in which I was overwriting the initialize method but forgot to call super.

I updated my question with the complete code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`layout` expects a string.

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"  

  def show
  end
end
```

A symbol calls the specified method which should return a template name (as a string).

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  layout :grab_bag  

  def show
  end

  def grab_bag
    ["red", "white", "blue"].sample
  end
end
```